# pip install python-twitter Error

Tags: python, pip

After making sure that pip is installed, I tried installing the twitter package using pip install python-twitter in the terminal but i get this error:

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/d1/49j6jy0d7hd_5cb6__cqwzhw0000gn/T/pip-build-5dzoDc/oauthlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/d1/49j6jy0d7hd_5cb6__cqwzhw0000gn/T/pip-GuXf_v-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/d1/49j6jy0d7hd_5cb6__cqwzhw0000gn/T/pip-build-5dzoDc/oauthlib/

It's worth noting I have Python 3.6 installed on a Mac, apart from the default 2.7.

The code also ends with this "error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauthlib': Permission denied"

Comment: The code also ends with this "error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauthlib': Permission denied"

Comment: Hi loana114.  I took the liberty of including your comment in the question.  It sounds like it will be relevant and useful to those who will help you.  It's a good thing to [edit] your questions with pertinent information, instead of leaving it in the comment block.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip install python-twitter`?

Comment: I believe error code 1 when installing with pip generally means that it does not have access to write to where it wants to install. I am not familiar with OS X, but on linux you can do `pip install <package-name> --user` to make it install in a directory for the user where it should have access. But it is only available for that user